# Generalized eigenvalue problem (only the smallest eigenvalue wanted), algorithm suggestion

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I have to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem

$$ A x = \lambda B x ,$$

where $A $ and $B$ are both hermitian, and in particular, $B$ is positive-definite. But they are both dense.

I just want the **smallest eigenvalue**.

What is the best algorithm for this purpose? Is there any openly available routine?

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, you best bet is to do the $O(m^3)$ arithmetic operations needed to find all $m$ generalized eigenvalues using a standard dense algorithm.

The TraceMIN algorithm can be used to compute the smallest eigenvalues for the Hermitian generalized eigenvalue problem $$Ax = \lambda Bx$$ where $B$ is positive-definite. The fundamental obstacle is that you need the ability to solve linear systems of the form $$AZ=BY$$ with respect to $Z$. The solve does not have to be exact so it is an option to use an iterative solver and avoid the $O(m^3)$ cost associated with computing a factorization of the dense matrix $A$. As one might expect the convergence of the TraceMIN algorithm depends on the separation of the eigenvalues. Ideally, you have a small cluster near zero and then a small gap before the next eigenvalue. In short, there is a small chance that you can accomplish your goal using $O(m^2)$ arithmetic operations.

This is a [link](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0719089) to the original paper by Sameh and Wisniewski on the TraceMIN algorithm.